# python read excel and search data

Tags: python-3.8

It is currently possible to read excel forms, but the function I want is to allow users to directly print out the corresponding content after entering the row and column item. Is there a sample grammar for reference?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlrd
sheets=pd.ExcelFile('D:\data.xlsx')
df1=pd.read_excel(sheets,'a')
df1.columns=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
list_t=range(10,50,5) # columns table list
list_d=np.arange(1,3.5,0.5) # row table list
```

#user input

```
d=float(input("d=")) #input column item
t=input(input("t=")) #input row item
```

Comment: I am not  very clear by what you mean by column item and row item? can you please give an example

Comment: For example, to query train tickets, you will first select the "starting location"(row_item) and "destination"(column_item), and finally display the train fare

Comment: The row and column inputs are numbers?

Comment: input :column is float ,row is int , output: read data is float

Comment: Why not just to read the rows as a double array , and then when you want access a cell you just use name_of_array[t][d]?